# asp.net stored procedure,multiple values in a single parameter

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, stored-procedures

Im fairly new to Asp.Net arena here guys,so please bear with me if say something that's not logical.

I have a procedure that binds to a grid-view that displays data based on the selection made from a drop-down box. It works fine when a single value is sent but I'm thinking of doing multiple selection from the drop-down[using checkboxes] or even using a list-view, and I'm confused how to go about it. This is the code for the stored procedure. At the moment it accepts only a single value. For e.g., if I select Africa from the drop-down it displays all the cities from Africa. But now I would like to have multiple selections for the drop-down so that the grid display cities from more than one country.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE sp_getCities 
(
@p_country  nvarchar(50)
)
AS

SELECT country, cities
FROM world WHERE country=@p_country
```

I'm sure there are people who must have come across situations like this. If you have could you please provide me with a link to a tutorial or a solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the (almost canonical) answer:

- [Arrays and Lists in SQL Server](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to pass XML into a stored procedure and using the system stored procedure sp_xml_preparedocument. Essentially, you pass XML into the stored procedure and operate on it in a SET oriented manner.

Check out this link to get you started with this approach.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187367.aspx